# Match a line without number followed by "."

Tags: regex

**Update:** I would like to match a line, started with `("` followed by a number and then anything except "." . For example

> `("10 Advanced topics 365" "#382")`

is a match, while

```
("10.1 Approximation Algorithms 365" "#382")
```

is not a match.

My regex is

```
^\(\"\d+(?!\.).*?$
```

but it will match both examples above including the second one. So what am I missing here?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: in what environment are you trying to match this?

Comment: @leppie: That is not a match.

Comment: @matchew: I am talking about python-style regex, but not in python programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Via update**:

```
^\("\d[^.]*$
```

Try this pattern:

```
(?m)^(?!.*?\d\.).*$
```

Comment: You could simplify that; lookahead constraints are typically matched non-greedily anyway. (Whether to use `(?m)` depends on how the data is being presented, which we're not being told.)

Comment: @polishchuk: Thanks! My original post was misleading. I was not clear about what I wanted to achieve. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to exclude the case when the number is followed *immediately* by ".", not that "." can be anywhere behind the number.

Comment: @Tim, Try this: ^\\("\d[^.]*$

Comment: @polishchuk: Thanks! (1) My parser says `^\("\d[^.]*$` is not a valid regex. What does `^` in the `[^.]`? (2) Also will `\d` match a whole number such as `10`, because I thought it will only match `1`. (3) I was wondering why my original attempt `^\(\"\d+(?!\.).*?$` will match the second example in the original post?

Comment: @Tim, (1) [^.] means any character except . (2) right, only 1

Comment: Thanks! (1) It works! (2) why does my original attempt `^\(\"\d+(?!\.).*?$` not work? I.e. it matches the second example in the original post?

Comment: @Tim, try yours modified `^\(\"\d+(?!\d*?\.).*?$`

Comment: Thanks! It works too. Isn't `\d+` greedy matching? Why in `("10.1`, regex `^\(\"\d+(?!\.)` matches `("1` instead of not matching?

Comment: @Tim, this regex means `... any digit, one or more repetitions; match if suffix "." is absent`, so `("10.1` satisfies this pattern

Answer (score 2):

While it's possible to write a RE that will match such a thing (see *manji*'s answer) I hate such things; they're very hard to comprehend later on. I find it's easier to write an RE to match the case that you don't want, and then make the rest of the logic of the program conditional on that RE *not* matching. This is virtually always trivial to do.

---

**EDIT:**
Sometimes you can do better. If we're seeking to distinguish between the types of lines you describe, where good lines don't have a period after the first digit and there's always some text at that point:

```
("10 Advanced topics 365" "#382")
("10.1 Approximation Algorithms 365" "#382")
```

Then a regular expression of this form will suffice:

```
^\("\d+[^.].*
```

Potentially you might need more to properly match the remainder of the line more precisely (e.g., detecting whether it ends with the right character sequence) but that's separate.

Comment: Thanks! My original post was misleading. I was not clear about what I wanted to achieve. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @Tim: Updated with the sort of thing you might use. You could also put `"\)$` on the end I suppose, but I don't know the full range of things you've got to deal with…